# Is there any option to export the heatmap from heatmaply in .svg format

Tags: r, heatmaply

I am wonder if there is any option to export the heatmap in svg or pdf format.

Comment: Hi Carlos, Have you tried any ways of exporting it? Could you please give us a few more details on what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this and it worked

```
webshot::install_phantomjs()
heatmaply(mtcars, file = "heatmaply_plot.pdf")
```

(source : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html )